# Was John Ashe about to testify about Clinton before he died of a crushed throat?

Tags: united-states, mortality, hillary-clinton

[WhatReallyHappened](http://www.whatreallyhappened.com/RANCHO/POLITICS/BODIES.php) writes:

> Initially reported as having died from a heart attack, John's throat had obviously been crushed. At that point the official story changed to him accidentally dropping a barbell on his own throat (the plotline from the episode "An Exercise in Fatality" from the TV series "Columbo.") crushing his larynx.
>
> Ashe was about to begin trial for a bribery charge involving Chinese businessman Ng Lap Seng, who had been implicated but not charged in the 1996 "China-gate" scandal for funneling illegal donations to Bill Clinton's re-election fund through Arkansas restaurant owner Charlie Trie. Ashe was supposed to testify about Hillary's links to Ng Lap Seng later the same day he died.

Is this an accurate description of the situation?

Comment: I've reworded the title to fit the claim.

Comment: Snopes categorizes it as "mostly false." http://www.snopes.com/un-official-john-ashe-killed-the-day-before-he-was-to-testify-against-hillary-clinton/

Comment: To be specific, he wasn't about to testify that day and his testimony wasn't about Clinton.  Most incorrect is that a heart attack did not figure into the Columbo episode.

Comment: @rougon: though there was a fake heart attack three episodes later in "Troubled Waters" - I suspect Peter Falk was somehow involved to tie the two together, especially as he was born in New York City and died very soon (less than three years) after Hillary Clinton stopped being US Senator for New York